# Cannot get my delete button link to show up in django

Tags: python, django

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code to get my delete message link to show up. All help is greatly appreciated.

views.py

```
def remove_message(request, message_id):
    Message.objects.filter(id=message_id, user=request.user).delete()
    return redirect(reverse('dashboard:show', args=user_id))
```

show.html

```
    {% for message in messages%}
    <div class="message">
        <p class='bg-primary wall_content'><strong>{{message.messageuser.first_name}} wrote:</strong></p>
        <p class='wall_content'>{{message.message}}</p>
        {% if message.id == request.user %}
        <a href='{% url "dashboard:remove_message" message.id %}'>Delete Message</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

message model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    walluser = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='userwall')
    messageuser = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='usermessage')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi one last question.  When changing the if statement to message.messageuser.id its not equal to the request.user.id, But it is when I use message.user.id. The message.user.id give me an anonymous user error.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.Can you please explain more ?

Comment: Of course.  When i use the message.messageuser.id == request.user.id. the delete button disappears again. If I use message.user.id the delete button shows up, but give me 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable error.  Do I need to change something in my urls or view to make message.messageuser.id == request.user.id?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128601/discussion-between-prakhar-trivedi-and-jives).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your template code,in the if condition :

```
{% if message.id == request.user %}
```

Here message.id in always not equal to request.user 
So you need to check this condition and update your code according to your models.
Something like this :

```
{% for message in messages %}
<div class="message">
    <p class='bg-primary wall_content'><strong>{{message.messageuser.first_name}} wrote:</strong></p>
    <p class='wall_content'>{{message.message}}</p>
    {% if message.messageuser.id == request.user.id %}
    <a href='{% url "dashboard:remove_message" message.id %}'>Delete Message</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: And a plus 1 for being less lazy than I.

Comment: @Pythonista Ha ha..Good one :D

Answer (score 2):

It seems unlikely that `message.id` will be equal to the `request.user` *object*